# Xcode : sharing content via Action Sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiactionsheet

I would like to replicate this behaviour (see image below) and share contents from my app using this kind of action sheet.

[image]

**The question is:**

Is this really an Action Sheet? I can't find anywhere tutorial for iOS 7 or 8. Not sure how to proceed.

Do the sharing options depends on user's configurations?

Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: its `UIActivityViewController` ...not  an actionsheet

Comment: How can we add Instagram in UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It is not in `UIActionSheet` it is in `UIActivityController`, which is the default function in iOS.

**objective-C**

```
- (void)presentActivityController:(UIActivityViewController *)controller {

    // for iPad: make the presentation a Popover
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

    // access the completion handler
    controller.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType,
                                              BOOL completed,
                                              NSArray *returnedItems,
                                              NSError *error){
        // react to the completion
        if (completed) {
            // user shared an item
            NSLog(@"We used activity type%@", activityType);
        } else {
            // user cancelled
            NSLog(@"We didn't want to share anything after all.");
        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An Error occured: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);
        }
    };
}

-(void)sendMessage {
    //create a message
    NSString *theMessage = @"Some text we're sharing with an activity controller";
    NSArray *items = @[theMessage];

    // build an activity view controller
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

    // and present it
    [self presentActivityController:controller];
}
```

**Swift**

```
let shareText = "Hello, world!"

if let image = UIImage(named: "myImage") {
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, image], applicationActivities: [])
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Try these links for tutorials

1. http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/
2. http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/
3. http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/02/how-to-add-facebook-and-twitter-sharing-to-an-ios-app/

**Swift**

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-share-content-with-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-share-content-with-uiactivityviewcontroller - this link was especially helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this result by using UIActivityController class.

Please take a look at this link :- http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Hope this helps!