# How to get iOS app such that i can share it via whatsapp or any other messenger

Tags: ios

Well this question seems silly but its just the need now. I want to share my iOS app via any messenger so that other person can install it in its iPhone and test it.

I also want to know about the further process such as -

1. How to install app after receiving it.

Comment: Your app is live on store ?

Comment: No. But whatever i made i want specific people to test it and thats why i need to share the app via any kind of messenger that supports sharing documents @AbhishekMishra

Comment: You can use test flight for share the app it is easy to share if you share by using other link (like diwi) at that time you need UDID of that specific device.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `UIActivityViewController` to present the sharing apps inside your app and you can send the itunes app link and message via that.
Now when somebody gets that message, he can touch the link you shared then it will redirect the user to your app in the appStore.
Please check the below link:

[Xcode : sharing content via Action Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941188/xcode-sharing-content-via-action-sheet)

Comment: My app isn't uploaded yet.

Comment: You can use testFlight to send your app to specific people, using itunes connect.

Comment: what if there is no developer account setuped for the app. Its just an app on the xcode

Comment: If you don't have any developer account then you can't even run your app on iOS device, only you can run on simulator.

Comment: isn't it is possible via connecting iPhone to xcode and build app seleting the iPhone. And i guess that doesn't required any developer account unless you provide provisioning profile

Comment: See if you have development certificate and provisioning profile of others and installed in your machine, and the provisioning profile include your device then also you can run on device.

Comment: yeah thats what i mean

Answer (score 1):

If your app is live than share itune link. if your app is not on appstore then create a url of app using enterprise certificates and share url. here are some tools for create url.

[AppBox](http://www.tryappbox.com)

[diwi](https://www.diawi.com)

**Update:-** You must need an apple developer or enterprise account for share and run app in real iphone device.

Comment: @ikdc pls explain how

Comment: My mistake, I see that your answer is in fact pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to share the app in iOS for testing ... `[TestFlight]` .

for more information -

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/