# Open Facebook share link on website on Facebook iOS/Android app

Tags: facebook

I have a simple scenario that I can't seem to find the answer to.

Scenario:

On my website I have [Facebook share link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). When clicked I want:

- If the user is on a mobile device - open in Facebook app if they have it, else open in browser
- If user is on a PC - open in browser

At the moment all that happens is it opens in the browser. This isn't good as hardly anyone is logged into Facebook on their mobile browser which is going to result in lots of users dropping out and not logging in to share.

I've found a few questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106447/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-share-on-facebook-link-that-opens-the-native-face) on Stack Overflow but they are old and nobody seems to have found a solution.

Is this achievable? Seems odd that you can't open the Facebook Share Dialog in the Facebook app.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can control that flow in any way and is actually up to the facebook msite version to redirect people to the App or at least show the banner to "Open in native App", which I believe they already do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to generate a 'share on Facebook' link that opens the native Facebook App on Android/iOS/mobile instead of the web share dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106447/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-share-on-facebook-link-that-opens-the-native-face)